# golang servehttp calls itself?

Tags: go

Really cannot understand ServeHTTP. I get that it's interface for the Handler and any object that implments ServeHTTP can behave as Handler. My question is the source code

```
func (sh serverHandler) ServeHTTP(rw ResponseWriter, req *Request) {
    handler := sh.srv.Handler
    if handler == nil {
        handler = DefaultServeMux
    }
    handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}
```

This line handler.ServeHTTP seems to be calling itself again??
handler is basically Server.Handler so it's calling itself all over again? What is the purpose of this method here? Is this just prototype? Can someone explain when you don't implment your own serveHTTP.. how does this function work?

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger. If you don't know how, try to find a video tutorial for whatever IDE you're using, it's an invaluable skill. That said, `sh` is not `handler` and the two may have methods with the same name which are still distinct.

Comment: `handler` will be either `DefaultServeMux` or a nested field inside `serverHandler`. It just happens that those also have a method with the same signature, but they are different types and different methods.

Comment: thank you guys. I will do them

Answer (score 0):

`serverHandler` is an adapter whose purpose is to set things up such that `DefaultServeMux` is used when a `nil` handler is passed to `ServeHTTP`. The `net/http` package is full of implementations of the `http.Handler` interface, because it's very useful and composable.

It's created like this:

```
serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
```

And `c.server` (the connection's server) is what `sh.srv` is accessing. **So it's not calling itself**. Note that the `Server` type is:

```
// A Server defines parameters for running an HTTP server.
// The zero value for Server is a valid configuration.
type Server struct {
    // Addr optionally specifies the TCP address for the server to listen on,
    // in the form "host:port". If empty, ":http" (port 80) is used.
    // The service names are defined in RFC 6335 and assigned by IANA.
    // See net.Dial for details of the address format.
    Addr string

    Handler Handler // handler to invoke, http.DefaultServeMux if nil

    {...} other fields
}
```

The `Handler` field can be legitimately `nil`, and it's the goal of `serverHandler` to handle this scenario.

I think you'll be interested in reading [this post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2021/life-of-an-http-request-in-a-go-server/) which explains the flow of events in the `net/http` package in detail.